# Timeout on individual threads in Executors.newFixedThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am creating user threads and putting them in fixed pool of size=5. I want my threads to be executed within 5 minutes. These threads done some database operations on remote server. But due to network delay, some threads just stops and waits for response from the remote server, and hence it causes delay which I donot want. So I want all of my pending threads finish within 5 minutes or else they should be killed or interrupted on certain timeout. How can I achieve that.

I am using Jdk.1.6.0_45

```
        int i = 0;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        while (i < 10) {
            ThreadClass thread = new ThreadClass();
            thread.setCounter(i);
            executor.execute(thread);
            i++;
        }           
        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Wiating for threads to terminate");

        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}

        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Comment: The name 'ThreadClass' suggests that it is a subclass of Thread. Is that true, or is it just an implementation of Runnable?

Comment: Yes it is subclass of Thread.

Comment: Then it's wrong. Differ between task and thread. A task is a piece of work that has to be done (usually a Runnable). A thread is a mechanism to run code in parallel. Executors already use threads internally to execute tasks. ThreadClass should be a task. Rename it and don't derive from Thread but implement Runnable instead!

Comment: I've now made changes to my code accordingly, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
executor.shutdown();
if (!executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
    executor.shutdownNow();
}
```

This will work only if your threads block on some function which tests for interruptions. Otherwise you can't do much: there is no way to reliably stop a thread, other than an interrupt.